# Bootstrap navbar: whitespace appears when collapsed (Rails app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar

I've read some different solutions to this but none that are specific to a Rails app and therefore I can't quite find the fix.  I've got a rails app that is using twitter bootstrap.  I'm using their responsive features in the navbar, when the viewport shrinks the icons on the navbar collapse into a dropdown button...  One issue I'm having is that when the navbar collapses both on the desktop and the mobile phone, I get whitespace above the navbar.  I've read about putting some inline style in that adjusts the padding, specifically:

```
<style type="text/css">
        body {
            padding-top: 60px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
        }
</style>
```

The problem is that, as per what I've read, I'm supposed to put this between the style sheet links in my header.  Problem is I'm not including the stylesheets the same way as the generic web apps I've seen the examples for (this is a Rails app).  Additonally, this is my first web app and I'm a little confused with exactly how things are getting pulled in.  (This is built upon the Rails Tutorial...).  Here's what I've got in my head.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>

  <!-- SETUP FOR RESPONSIVE BOOTSTRAP -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link href="app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss">

</head>
```

I'm including bootstrap in my "custom.css.scss" file (pulled in with link above) with:

```
@import "bootstrap"
@import "bootstrap-responsive"
```

I'm not sure if a simple css style rule would fix this or if it would require something more.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I tried the style rule mentioned at the top, both at the top of my head and just before the href to the custom.css.scss file and neither effected the navbar...

This link mentions the padding fix, but I'm not including the stylesheets directly so I don't know where to put the padding fix... http://blog.benca.net/2012/03/17/css-order-matters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, for future reference.  I'm not sure exactly how I went wrong as I was working my way through the Rails Tutorial the second time but creating a custom web app in parallel.  What I've found is this:

Somewhere along the way in the "Universal" .css that we add in the Tutorial, we add `body { padding-top: 60px; }`.  When I inspected app in shrunk/scaled down mode, this is exactly the padding that was showing up.  For some reason, this padding doesn't show up when the viewport is wide/big (desktop size), but does when it is shrunk.  I simply took out this padding and Boom!, the navbar lined up nicely when shrunk and had no effect when big.  Hope this might help someone who is learning from the tutorial while taking things in a responsive direction at the same time.  Cheers.

Comment: Just for the record it wasn't you because I found strangely found this in my code too!

Comment: This is because, for screens 980px and up, `.navbar-fixed-top` uses `position: fixed`, removing it from the normal flow and causing body content to move up 60px. That's why you added the `body { padding-top: 60px; }` style. But below 980px, `.navbar-fixed-top` reverts to `position: static`, making that extra padding unnecessary.

Comment: Even with this setup, you do not need to completely remove the `body { padding-top: 60px; }` line.  In Custom.css.scss, you can just move this line above `@import "bootstrap-responsive"`

Answer (score 1):

Simply wrap your padding rules for body with @media rule:

```
@media (min-width: 980px) {
    body {
        padding-top: 60px;
    }
 }
```

This will apply body padding only with fixed navbar.